# One Service data Multiple Activity in android

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin

Hi I make Android application for Xamarin. I have created a simple application in the Android studio. so any answer welcome either Java or C#
I have a service(GPS service) and 2 Activities.
MainActivity - GPS service are well connected with the broadcast.  I hope MainActivity -> Another activity real time GPS point.(It is also okay to send from the GPS service to another activity.) but it is fail...app is dead..

MainActivity code

```
    private void RegisterService()
    {
        _gpsServiceConnection = new GPSServiceConnection(_binder);
        _gpsServiceIntent = new Intent(Android.App.Application.Context, typeof(GPS.GPSService));
        BindService(_gpsServiceIntent, _gpsServiceConnection, Bind.AutoCreate);
    }

    private void RegisterBroadcastReceiver()
    {
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(GPSServiceReciever.LOCATION_UPDATED);
        filter.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryDefault);
        _receiver = new GPSServiceReciever();
        RegisterReceiver(_receiver, filter);
    }

    private void UnRegisterBroadcastReceiver()
    {
        UnregisterReceiver(_receiver);
    }

    public void UpdateUI(Intent intent)
    {
        LatLng_txt.Text = intent.GetStringExtra("Location");
        Lat = intent.GetDoubleExtra("Lat", 0.0);
        Lng = intent.GetDoubleExtra("Lng", 0.0);
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        RegisterBroadcastReceiver();
    }

    protected override void OnPause()
    {
        base.OnPause();
        UnRegisterBroadcastReceiver();
    }

    [BroadcastReceiver]
    internal class GPSServiceReciever : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public static readonly string LOCATION_UPDATED = "LOCATION_UPDATED";
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            if (intent.Action.Equals(LOCATION_UPDATED))
            {
                Instance.UpdateUI(intent);

            }
        }
    }
```

GPS Service code

```
public void OnLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        try
        {
            _currentLocation = location;

            if (_currentLocation == null)
            {
                _location = "Unable to determine your location.";
            }
            else
            {
                _location = String.Format("{0}, {1}", _currentLocation.Latitude, _currentLocation.Longitude);

                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);

                IList<Address> addressList = geocoder.GetFromLocation(_currentLocation.Latitude,
                    _currentLocation.Longitude, 10);

                Address addressCurrent = addressList.FirstOrDefault();

                if (addressCurrent != null)
                {
                    StringBuilder deviceAddress = new StringBuilder();

                    for (int i = 0; i < addressCurrent.MaxAddressLineIndex; i++)
                    {
                        deviceAddress.Append(addressCurrent.GetAddressLine(i)).AppendLine(",");
                    }

                    _address = deviceAddress.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    _address = "Unable to determine the address.";
                }

                IList<Address> source = geocoder.GetFromLocationName(_sourceAddress, 1);
                Address addressOrigin = source.FirstOrDefault();

                var coord1 = new LatLng(addressOrigin.Latitude, addressOrigin.Longitude);
                var coord2 = new LatLng(addressCurrent.Latitude, addressCurrent.Longitude);

                var distanceInRadius = Utils.HaversineDistance(coord1, coord2, Utils.DistanceUnit.Miles);

                _remarks = string.Format("Your are {0} miles away from your original location.", distanceInRadius);

                Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity.GPSServiceReciever));
                intent.SetAction(MainActivity.GPSServiceReciever.LOCATION_UPDATED);
                intent.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryDefault);
                intent.PutExtra("Location", _location);
                intent.PutExtra("Lat", _currentLocation.Latitude);
                intent.PutExtra("Lng", _currentLocation.Longitude);
                SendBroadcast(intent);

            }
        }
        catch
        {
            _address = "Unable to determine the address.";
        }

    }
```

Is not there a good way?

Comment: As far as I have understood your problem, you want to send data from one `Activity` to another via `Service`. Am I right?

Comment: MainActivity and another activity are need real time GPS point data. so I tried to send directly and also tried to send two intents from the service but it failed...

Answer (score 0):

I understood your problem.But dont know more about GPS etc.I have faced the same problem when I was creating Music App.
Two activities were there and one service.And successfully got real time song position and song data from both activities.

My MainActivity has

```
ServiceConnection sc=null;
public static PlayerService ps;
```

And gets its value in onCreate of MainActivity

```
   sc=new ServiceConnection(){

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName p1, IBinder p2)
        {
            PlayerService.Getters getters=(PlayerService.Getters) p2;
            ps=getters.getService();
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName p1)
        {
            // TODO: Implement this method
        }

    };
```

Then PlayerService.Getters class is

```
public  class Getters extends Binder
{
    public PlayerService getService()
    {
        return PlayerService.this;
    }
}
```

PlayerService has

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent p1)
{
    return new Getters();
}
```

getService of Getters gives the object of PlayerService to my MainActivity.
Now I can get real time values of service variables and methods using static ps from multiple activities.

Comment: um.... I think  use to observer pattern. But it lacks the concept of design pattern and is not applicable.

Comment: I think it is easy to communicate with services from multiple activities. Because I have used the same and felt very simple.

Answer (score 0):

In order to send data or information from `Service` to `Activity`, you'll need to use  `Messenger` API. This API will allow you to create an inter process communication (IPC) i.e. a communication link between two or more processes. In Android, `Activity` and `Service` are two separate processes, so you can use the IPC technique to establish a communication link in between them.

In the IPC technique, there are two ends, the Server end and the Client end. The `Service` acts as the Server and `Activity` acts as the Client.

**Note: Service will only be able to communicate with one `Activity` at a time.**

`Messenger` allows for the implementation of message-based communication across processes by help of Handlers.

`Handler` is a that allows you to send and process these messages.

Steps for implementing a Messenger:

Step 1. Service implements a Handler which receives the callbacks from the Activity

Step 2. The Handler then creates a Messenger object which further on creates an IBinder that the Service returns to the Activity.

Step 3. Activity then uses the IBinder to instantiate the Messenger, which the Activity uses to send messages to the Service.

Step 4. The Service receives the messages in the Handler created in the 1st step.

Lets now understand it with an example:

Create a Handler in the Service like this:

```
class ServiceHandler extends Handler {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            default:
                super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, add the Messenger object along with onBind() method to the Service as mentioned in 2nd step above:

```
final Messenger messenger = new Messenger(new ServiceHandler());

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return messenger.getBinder();
}
```

In the Activity, we will create a ServiceConnection to fetch the iBinder from the Service to instantiate the Messenger object as mentioned in the 3rd step above.

```
Messenger messenger;
private ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder iBinder) {
        messenger = new Messenger(iBinder);
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
    }
};
```

Bind the Service to the Activity by help of the ServiceConnection created above:

```
bindService(new Intent(this, MessengerService.class), serviceConnection,
    Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

To send messages to the Service from the Activity, use the send() method of the Messenger object.

If you want to receive messages from the Service in the Activity, you need to create a Messenger in the Activity along with a Handler and use the replyTo parameter of the Messenger to receive messages to the respective Handler.